# How to change AmChart pie chart background?

Tags: charts, amcharts

How can I replace the color in the pie chart?

Please find my code below :

```
AmCharts.makeChart("pie-diagramm", {
        "type": "pie",
        "theme": "none",
        "dataProvider": [{
            "title": "Интернэшнл",
            "value": 100
        }, {
            "title": "Казахстан",
            "value": 90
        },{
            "title": "Лтд",
            "value": 100
            },
            {
            "title": "Лимитед",
            "value": 400},
            {
                "title": "компания",
                "value": 400},
            {
                "title": "ЛУКАРКО",
                "value": 600},{

                "title": "Компани",
                "value": 700
                },
            {

                "title": "«КазМунайГаз»",
                "value": 900},{

                "title": "КТК",
                "value": 350},
            {

                "title": "Федерация",
                "value": 1300},
            {

                "title": "Пайплайн",
                "value": 90}
        ],
        "titleField": "title",
        "valueField": "value",
        "labelRadius": 5,
        "fontSize": 16,
        "radius": "25%",
        "innerRadius": "30%",
        "labelText": "[[title]]",
        "exportConfig": {
            "menuItems": [{
                "icon": '/lib/3/images/export.png',
                "format": 'png'
            }]
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why is this tagged `highcharts`? To answer your question, though, read the API documentation: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart, look at the `colors` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

add color attribute in your DataProvider

dataProvider": [{
            "title": "Интернэшнл",
            "value": 100,
            ***"color": "your choice of color"***
        }, {
            "title": "Казахстан",
            "value": 90,
            ***"color": "your choice of color"***
        }

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart,
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Slice

the dataprovider holds the property of each slice in pie chart

chart.chartData = dataProvider;

Answer (score 0):

The best and most simple way to do this would be setting background-color style of your chart's container div. Or you can set chart.backgroundColor="#FF0000"; and chart.backgroundAlpha to some bigger than 0 value.